# how to fetch result into array or how to fetch 'nid' out of result?

Tags: database

Good day to everyone!

some help needed with fetching result out of EntityFieldQuery. 
Have a unique value of the field. I try to get 'nid' of node by value of the field with help of EntityFieldQuery. my problem is that i dont know how to fetch result in a right way to get just 'nid'. then knowing nid i will be able to load the node and do some work with it.

```
$query = new EntityFieldQuery;
$entities = $query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
->entityCondition('bundle', 'order')
->fieldCondition('field_reference_number', 'value', $titleref)
->execute();
$result= $query->execute();
drupal_set_message('nid: ' .print_r($result, true));
```

my result is:

```
nid: Array ( [node] => Array ( [2250] => stdClass Object ( [nid] => 2250 [vid] => 2252 [type] => order ) ) )
```

how to fetch it corectly to get 'nid' out of it?

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way would be:

```
$result = $query->execute();

if (!empty($results['node'])) {
  $nids = array_keys($results['node']);
}
```

There are a few different ways to get the first nid out of the array if that's what you need; personally I prefer `reset()` as it's non-destructive to the original array (unlike `array_shift()` for example).

```
$first_nid = reset($nids);
```

If you then need the node objects you can pass that array straight to [`node_load_multiple()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.module/function/node_load_multiple/7):

```
$nodes = node_load_multiple($nids);
```

Comment: wasn't it too fast to answer ;)

Comment: @Mark I have to write pretty much identical code 20 times a day so it's stuck in my brain :)